# How can I show that $\left\lvert\sin z\right\rvert^2= \left\lvert\sin x\right\rvert^2 + \left\lvert\sinh y\right\rvert^2$ for $z= x+iy$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to show that $\left\lvert\sin z\right\rvert^2= \left\lvert\sin x\right\rvert^2 + \left\lvert\sinh y\right\rvert^2$ for $z= x+iy$

We have that

\begin{align}
\left\lvert\sin z\right\rvert^2 &= \left\lvert\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\right\rvert^2
\\&=\left\lvert\dfrac{1}{2i}e^{-y}\left(\cos x + i \sin x\right) -\dfrac{1}{2i}e^{y}\left(\cos x - i \sin x\right)\right\rvert^2
\\&=\left\lvert\dfrac{i}{2}\cos x\left(e^y-e^{-y}\right)
 +\frac{1}{2} \sin x\left(e^y+e^{-y}\right)\right\rvert^2
\\&=\left\lvert i \cos x \sinh y + \sin x \cosh y \right\rvert^2
\\&=\left(\cos^2 x \sinh^2 y + \sin^2 x \cosh^2 y\right) 
\end{align}

I am just not seeing it

Comment: Express cos in terms of sin and cosh in terms of sinh.

Comment: Apologies for being pedantic, but I take it you're given that $z=x+iy$ or $z=y+xi$ or something? There is work to justify what your question might be, but the question itself is incomplete.

Comment: yes sorry I should add that.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$ and $\cosh^2 y-\sinh^2 y=1$, $$\cos^2 x \sinh^2 y + \sin^2 x \cosh^2 y=(1-\sin^2x) \sinh^2 y + \sin^2 x (1+\sinh^2 y)=\sinh^2 y+\sin^2 x.$$
Since $\sin x$ and $\sinh y$ are real, $|\sin x|^2=\sin^2 x$ and $|\sinh y|^2=\sinh^2 y$, so this is what you want.